# Python: when copying folders shutil.copy2 method creates a .db file that wasn't in the original file folder, when copying files get NotADirectoryError

Tags: python, database, windows-10, shutil, file-copying

When I run this script to copy a file from the source to destination folder

```
def CopyFol_Subfolders(src, dst):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            CopyFol_Subfolders(s, d)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)

src = r'C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/TEMPORARY/GEOLOGY TO SEND/Well Logs/B/BAKER B E 1_42/BAKER-B-E-1_42_MICRO_1.TIF'
dst = r'C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/TEMPORARY/NTX-Wells/42'
```

Nothing is copied and I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotADirectoryError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-ff1a78fa2fd6> in <module>
----> 1 CopyFol_Subfolders(src, dst)

<ipython-input-36-1c270b8fee24> in CopyFol_Subfolders(src, dst)
      1 def CopyFol_Subfolders(src, dst):
----> 2     for item in os.listdir(src):
      3         s = os.path.join(src, item)
      4         d = os.path.join(dst, item)
      5         if os.path.isdir(s):

NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/TEMPORARY/GEOLOGY TO SEND/Well Logs/B/BAKER B E 1_42/BAKER-B-E-1_42_MICRO_1.TIF'
```

However, when I change the source file to the directory (delete the file extension from the "src" path) it copies everything in the directory and adds a .db file that wasn't there before. I just did this today (11/6/2021) but it shows the .db file as having been created in 2018, so it seemingly wasn't generated by running this code. Screenshot below.

```
src = r'C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/TEMPORARY/GEOLOGY TO SEND/Well Logs/B/BAKER B E 1_42'
dst = r'C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/TEMPORARY/NTX-Wells/42'
```

**Questions:**

1. Why am I getting the `NotADirectoryError` when trying to copy a file? `shutil.copy2` is supposed to be able to copy individual files.
2. Why is this `.db` file showing up in my destination folder that wasn't in my source folder? The settings in my file explorer are set to not hide any files. I'm not sure what program the `.db` file is associated with and there's no indication in the file properties--and no way to read it otherwise (that I know of). It's possible that the `.db` file is associated with some software (the data is from my work's database), but that doesn't answer why it would only appear when copying the folder. Very confused about this.

I have full administrator rights on my computer and run Conda as an administrator, so these problems shouldn't stem from accessibility issues.
**Running Python 3.8 on Conda Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0**

[image: Source and destination file folders]

Comment: Regarding your first question.  You're passing in a src argument that's a file, and then you're immediately calling os.listdir on it.  That's going to fail.  You need to check that it's a directory *before* attempting to list the directory on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Frank Yellin for pointing me in the right direction for Q1. I found the answer for Q2 (sort of).

The thumbs.db file is a Windows system file that's automatically generated (and automatically has 'attributes' designated as 'hidden') for folders containing images on Windows OS. It's a thumbnail cache -- allowing the File Explorer to display a thumbnail of the file's image. It's listed when calling the os.listdir() function.

What I still don't know is why the shutil.copy2 method changed the file from the 'hidden' state. Either way, it's not much of a problem for what I'm doing and I'll simply filter it out.